# Trouble with abstracting onMouseover/out javascript functions in a table, I want tidy HTML

Tags: javascript, dom, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am having trouble trying to put all of my onMouseOut and onMouseOver functions separate to my HTML in this table row that I have.

Before you ask, it has to be in JavaScript and not CSS.

This works:

```
<tr onMouseover="this.bgColor='#90D04E',style.fontWeight='bold'" onMouseout="this.bgColor='#FFFFFF',style.fontWeight='normal'">
```

However this doesn't:

```
function myF() {
document.getElementById("tr1").onMouseover = "this.bgColor='#90D04E',style.fontWeight='bold'";
document.getElementById("tr1").onMouseout = "this.bgColor='#FFFFFF',style.fontWeight='normal'";
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/p8ktw/)

As you can see the first three rows work how I want them to work, however the last row doesn't when I try to separate the code. Not sure why it doesn't work but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write this into your javascript section/file:

```
document.getElementById("tr1").onmouseover = function()
{    
  this.bgColor='#90D04E';
  this.style.fontWeight='bold';
}

document.getElementById("tr1").onmouseout = function()
{
  this.bgColor='#FFFFFF';
  this.style.fontWeight='normal';
}
```

In addition, there is no need to call some function on event that declared in tag body:

Change:

```
<tr onMouseover="myF();" onMouseout="myF();" id="tr1">
    <td>135</td>
    <td>Web Development</td>
</tr>
```

To:

```
<tr id="tr1">
    <td>135</td>
    <td>Web Development</td>
</tr>
```

According to your code, as if u call function on, for example, mouseover event u need to transfare the call (in example only onmouseover event):

```
<tr onMouseover="myF(this);" id="tr1">
    <td>135</td>
    <td>Web Development</td>
</tr>

<script>    
function myF(this) {
  this.bgColor='#90D04E';
  this.style.fontWeight='bold'";    
}
</script>
```

Don't forget to wrape your javascript code to window.load/$(document).ready callback, otherwise in time when javascript eval tags can be not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues there.

1. You're assigning to `this.bgColor`; you should assign to `this.style.backgroundColor`.
2. You're then assigning to `style.fontWeight` (missing the `this.` in front of it).
3. Assigning *strings* to `onXyz` handlers is not best practice.
4. You were *calling* `myF` for every mouseover/mouseout, but it should only be called *once*, to hook things up.
5. Hooking it up the way you were trying to would still pollute your HTML a fair bit.

With this markup (note how I've added `thead` and `tbody`):

```
<table border="1" width="60%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Module Code</th>
            <th>Module Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>Programming</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>102</td>
            <td>Databases</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>135</td>
            <td>Web Development</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can do this:

```
// Note the jsFiddle setting on the left: This
// is just before the closing </body> tag
(function() {
    var list;
    var n, row;

    // Get a list of all `tr` elements that are inside a `tbody`
    list =  = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

    // Loop through, assigning the handlers
    for (n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) {
        // Assign the handlers to these rows
        row = list[n];
        row.onmouseover = handleMouseOver;
        row.onmouseout = handleMouseOut;
    }

    // Our handlers   
    function handleMouseOver() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = '#90D04E';
        this.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    }

    function handleMouseOut() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
        this.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
    }
})();
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8ktw/3/)

Another option is *event delegation*; if you search around, you can find various articles on it.

As a side note, I would really use a class for this, rather than assigning values directly to the `style` object for the individual rows.